# Prove $[n\alpha]-[(n-1)\alpha]$ is $0$ or $1$.

Tags: analysis

> Prove that for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $[n\alpha]-[(n-1)\alpha]$ is $0$ or $1$, where $[.]$ denotes greatest integer function.

I tried proving this making several cases but it is becoming very long, can it be done shortly using some properties of greatest integer function?

Answer (score 3):

$n\alpha - (n-1)\alpha = \alpha \in(0, 1)$.

If there exists an integer $k$ such that $n\alpha \ge k > (n-1)\alpha$, then $[n\alpha] - [(n-1)\alpha] = k - (k-1) = 1$.

Otherwise, there is no integer in $((n-1)\alpha,n\alpha]$ in which case $[n\alpha] = [(n-1)\alpha]$.

Comment: That's so nicely done!